# Check ArrayList contains any data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've 3 `ScreenSlidePageFragment objects`. I'm showing my data by parsing a `json` file. Here is my main activity code :

```
public class ScheduleMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /*
     * Parsing JSON to get the array length
     */
    private void getLength() {
        try {
            BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this
                    .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.program)));
            StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = jsonReader.readLine()) != null;) {
                jsonBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonBuilder.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);
            totalPages = jsonArray.length();
            for(int counter = 0 ; counter < NUM_PAGES ; counter ++){
               JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(counter);
                   String getDate = jsonObject.getString("date");
                   ScheduleItem.dateWay.add(getDate);
    }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static int totalPages; //value = 3

    /**/

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally
     * to access previous and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
        getLength();
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents ScreenSlidePageFragment objects,
     * in sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //Log.e("#MA", position + "");
            return ScheduleSlideFragment.create(position, mPager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return totalPages;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I want to check if any previous `date` contains in data `ArrayList`. So, I tried this

```
 if(!ScheduleItem.dateWay.get(getPageNumber).contains(data.get(getPageNumber).getDate())){

            jsonParseData(getPageNumber);
        }
```

And It throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`.

Here is my `ScheduleSlideFragment` code

```
public class ScheduleSlideFragment extends Fragment {

    final static String ARG_PAGE = "page";

    private static ViewPager pager;

    private static int pageNumber;

    final static int totalPages = ScheduleMainActivity.totalPages;

    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //public List<ScheduleItem>[] data = (ArrayList<ScheduleItem>[])new ArrayList[totalPages];

    public ArrayList<ScheduleItem> data = new ArrayList<ScheduleItem>();

    public int getPageNumber;

    private void jsonParseData(int _getPageNumber) {
        try {
            BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this
                    .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.program)));
            StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = jsonReader.readLine()) != null;) {
                jsonBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Parse Json
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(jsonBuilder.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);
            _getPageNumber = getPageNumber;
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(_getPageNumber);
            String getDate = jsonObject.getString("date");
            JSONArray getFirstArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("events"));

            for (int i = 0; i < getFirstArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject getJSonObj = (JSONObject)getFirstArray.get(i);
                String time = getJSonObj.getString("time");
                //Log.e("Time Log",time);
                String type = getJSonObj.getString("type");
                String title = getJSonObj.getString("title");
                int typeId = getJSonObj.getInt("type_id");

                data.add(new ScheduleItem(time, title, typeId, getDate));

                /*
                 * Get Events
                 */
                if (typeId == 0) {

                    JSONArray getEventsArray = new JSONArray(getJSonObj.getString("events"));

                    for (int j = 0; j < getEventsArray.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject getJSonEventobj = (JSONObject)getEventsArray.get(j);
                        int typeEventId = getJSonEventobj.getInt("type_id");

                        if (typeEventId == 1) {

                            String EventInfo = getJSonEventobj.getString("info");
                            String EventType = getJSonEventobj.getString("type");
                            String EventTitle = getJSonEventobj.getString("title");
                            String Eventtime = getJSonEventobj.getString("time");
                            data.add(new ScheduleItem(Eventtime, EventTitle, EventInfo,
                                    typeEventId, getDate));
                        } else {

                            String EventType = getJSonEventobj.getString("type");
                            String EventTitle = getJSonEventobj.getString("title");
                            String Eventtime = getJSonEventobj.getString("time");
                            data.add(new ScheduleItem(Eventtime, EventTitle, typeEventId,
                                    getDate));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, container, false);
        getPageNumber = pageNumber;
        /** 
         * JSON Parsing 
         */
        if(!ScheduleItem.dateWay.get(getPageNumber).contains(data.get(getPageNumber).getDate())){

            jsonParseData(getPageNumber);
        }
        /**
         * Set header date 
         */
        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDay)).setText(data.get(pageNumber).getDate().toString());
        final ListView list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this.getActivity(), data);
        list.setAdapter(bindingData);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (data.get(position).getItemType() == 0
                        || data.get(position).getItemType() == 3
                        || data.get(position).getItemType() == 2)
                    return;
                Intent intent = new Intent(ScheduleSlideFragment.this.getActivity(),
                        ContentExtended.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", data.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("content", data.get(position).getContent());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibLeft = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ibLeft);
        if (pageNumber == 0)
            ibLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        else
            ibLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ibLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() > 0)
                    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibRight = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ibRight);
        if (pageNumber + 1 == totalPages)
            ibRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            ibRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ibRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pager.getCurrentItem() < totalPages)
                    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public static Fragment create(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new ScheduleSlideFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static Fragment create(int position, ViewPager _pager) {
        pageNumber = position;
        pager = _pager;
        Fragment fragment = new ScheduleSlideFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

}
```

My main problem is :

The data array contains all the data for one day/page at each position. In the current implementation(Without If condition), whenever someone opens say page three all data for page three is loaded, converted and stored in data at position 2.If we use such a data array the individual entries should not be recreated all of the time. So, I want to use a `if condition` to check data is available.

My Question is :

1) What are the alternatives way to way to check if `data` ArrayList contains any data??

2)How can I solve the the IndexOutOfBoundsException problem?

Comment: are you checking for these conditions before accessing `list != null`, `position < list.size()`

Comment: @R9j, make sure that `position` is also greater than `-1`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, i agree

Answer (score 2):

> 1) What are the alternatives way to way to check if data ArrayList
>   contains any data??

To check if an `ArrayList` contains any data, use the `isEmpty()` method, like so:

```
ArrayList<ScheduleItem> data = new ArrayList<ScheduleItem>();
if (!data.isEmpty()) { //data is not empty, meaning there is data....
```

> 2)How can I solve the the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` problem?

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you try to get an item in an indexed position that is out of range.

Out of range is when between `[0, size() - 1]` where `size()` is the size of the `ArrayList()`.

To simply check if you're out of bounds, do something of this effect...

```
if ( i < 0 || i >= size()) { // Don't get item from an ArrayList, it's out of bounds
```

In your case:

```
if ( _getPageNumber >=0 &&  _getPageNumber < data.size()) { //Get item from jsonArray...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried if ( _getPageNumber >=0 &&  _getPageNumber < data.size()). Still I got : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: That means your array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions

1) You can check if data has any data with `if (data != null && data.size() > 0)`

2) You can avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` by validating that `if (getPageNumber > 0 && getPageNumber < data.size())`

Comment: what if `getPageNumber` is less than zero?

Comment: I tried if ( getPageNumber >0 && getPageNumber < data.size()). Still I got : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Is "dateWay" also a Collection ? If so, you should do the same validations

Answer (score 0):

I think first place to look for general purpose java APIs is [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/). For your particular case (check if a collection is not empty) - see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.util.Collection%29.